# Combinations for two columns from two different tables

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

Suppose I have two tables:

Suppliers:

| id_supplier | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Supplier 1 |
| 2 | Supplier 2 |
| 3 | Supplier 3 |

Dates

| id_pk | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-12-29 |
| 2 | 2022-12-30 |
| 2 | 2022-12-31 |

For each dates, how can get a result set that lists all suppliers per date as follows?

| date | supplier |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-29 | Supplier 1 |
| 2022-12-29 | Supplier 2 |
| 2022-12-29 | Supplier 3 |
| 2022-12-30 | Supplier 1 |
| 2022-12-30 | Supplier 2 |
| 2022-12-30 | Supplier 3 |
| 2022-12-31 | Supplier 1 |
| 2022-12-32 | Supplier 2 |
| 2022-12-33 | Supplier 3 |

In essence a list of all combinations for the two columns from two different tables?

Comment: Check cross join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a simple CROSS JOIN:

```
select date, name from Dates, Suppliers
```

Comment: Now I feel rather silly.  Thanks!